# Posts handled outside of /review do not count within review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just handled [How to use markdown in card description?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-use-markdown-in-card-description), and edited it. Now going to /review it seems that I did not review the question as it shows up there (which I didn't if one thinks of review as browsing questions from /review).

[image: review example]

Is this the intended behaviour? I would like to assume that no matter where the post is handled, it should be marked as reviewed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the intended behaviour right now, although there is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111482/include-reviews-made-outside-of-review-in-progress-towards-the-badge) up on Meta Stack Overflow to change it.